# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unsupported connection setting AUTO_SERVER

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

While trying the create H2 database connection with the following URL,

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:D:/HATBOX/Data;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE")
```

I get the following exception. Can anyone explain what i am missing here.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unsupported connection setting AUTO_SERVER [90113-73]
at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:103)
at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:114)
at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:77)
at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.readSettingsFromURL(ConnectionInfo.java:189)
at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.<init>(ConnectionInfo.java:87)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:87)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:57)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.company.h2.TestInsert.main(TestInsert.java:16)
```

I need to use AUTO_SERVER=true as i am trying to configure HatBox with my application ,so that multiple processes can access the same database without having to start the server manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very old version of H2 (version 1.0.73 from 2008-05-31) where this option is not supported.

I suggest to upgrade to a recent version of H2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas, but i am using the latest jar only. How did you thought that i am using 1.0.73 version?

Comment: You are using version 1.0.73, because the build number is encoded in the error code. [90113-73] means build number 73 is used, which is version 1.0.73. In many cases the problem is that multiple h2 jar files are in the classpath, so that you can't be sure which jar file is used.